# python: calling java program

Tags: java, python, jar

I have a tag cloud generator that I would like to call from my python program. How can I do it?

I run it in a batch file

```
java -jar ibm-word-cloud.jar -C configure.txt input.txt output.png
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is now [preferred over os.system()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system).  A simple example, assuming run_prog.bat contains the command you need:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "run_prog.bat"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the os module:

```
import os
os.system('mybatchfile.bat')
```

or use the subprocess module